# search lines until match then assign value to variable

Tags: awk

Using AWK I'd like to read a line and set the selected output to a variable, which ultimately we'll use to call from a DB. After mucho Googling I find myself lost. I don't get any syntax errors, just no output love.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Line 270: Ping statistics for 69.168.188.77:
Line 271: Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 100, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Line 272: Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Line 273: Minimum = 612ms, Maximum = 657ms, Average = 633ms
```

I've been trying something like this..

```
extpinglostvalue=`awk '{print $10 ; if (NR =271) print ""}' filename.txt`
echo -e "Value is $extpinglostvalue"
```

Comment: But what do you want to print? The `0` in `Lost = 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to capture `0` (the value after `Lost =` in your variable then you can do:

```
extpinglostvalue=$(awk 'NR==271{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="Lost")print $(i+2)}' filename.txt)
```

#### Explanation:

- `NR==271`: This performs our action on line number 271
- Our action is to iterate over each fields of the line delimited by space. When we encounter the field that is `Lost` we grab the second field after it (since there is an `=` to in between we need to skip.
- Use command substitution `$(..)` instead of backticks.

Comment: Brilliant. That's going to take me a few to figure out how it works but it does. Cheers gentlemen. As always, really do appreciate it.

Comment: @user3433321 Added some explanation. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get number of Lost packets:

```
awk '/Packets: Sent/{print $10}' file
0
```